# Vertically fit middle element with scroll using UIKit/HTML5

Tags: html, css, uikit

I'm trying to create a layout with 3 elements. The first and last elements have constant height. I want the middle element to have flexible height based on the viewport and a scroll.

```
+--------------------+
|                    |
|         1          |
+--------------------+
|                    ||
| Adjusts with Window||
|     Height         ||
|                    ||
|         2          ||
|                    ||
+--------------------+
|         3          |
|                    |
+--------------------+
```

Here is what I have done so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/zpe9s4wv/11/

The issue with my fiddle is that there is space between the elements. Also the elements do not cover exactly 100% on the view port height like I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your css, seeing as uk-grid had a set margin:

```
.uk-grid {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

If you don't want to remove the margin for all grids, specify the grids you want to alter instead, for example:

```
.uk-grid.green {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Also add to your class:

```
.green {
...
height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What we have here uk-grid-collapse will remove margin between blocks.
uk-child-width-1-1 will add 100% width to all children blocks (better visibility of code). I know it is old question but may be my answer will help someone.

```css
.red{
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
.green{
  background-color: green;
}

.blue{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.10/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.10/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="uk-child-width-1-1 uk-grid-collapse" uk-grid >
  <div class="red">
    
  </div>
  <div class="green" uk-height-viewport="offset-top: true; offset-bottom: true">
    
  </div>
   <div class="blue">
    
  </div>
</div>
```